# Python Flask complains of a "No module named demo" error when running from VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask, debugging, virtualenv

I have a super simple flask application:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask("__name__")


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "random, World!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is in a file called `demo.py` in a large VSCode Repository

For some reason, when I try and run this code, I get this command line behaviour:

```
 * Serving Flask app '__name__' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with watchdog (windowsapi)
No module named demo
```

Whereas when I run the same program via navigating to it in command prompt, and just using `python demo.py` it runs fine.

Note my python version is `10.5`

Any help at all would be appreciated, `demo.py` is in a repository opened up in vscode and I am pretty sure that is why this is happening. But I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: Added content:

It seems that the error occurs when within a folder, but when the script is in the root of the project it works fine?

Comment: First thought when I see this is that vscode isn't properly configured to use your desired virtual environment. Open the vscode command palette and make sure you have the correct venv selected.

Comment: Detail the procedure by which you got the error.

Comment: Was the `__name__` quoted intentionally? What's with passing standard import name `app = Flask(__name__)`?